# Java best data structure for sorting?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, treemap

I want to store a list of (Object, int) in a data structure such that the int field can be easily sorted (ascending or descending).
I'm looking at Hashtables and TreeMaps but i'm unsure  which, if either, of these are good for this purpose.
The priority is the sort speed. Any suggestions?

Comment: `TreeMap` sorts by key, not by value. If you could inverse (Object, int) to (int, Object), that would fit.

Comment: Yes, TreeMap will be suitable. I don't think this is a good question... "I'm looking at" - nice, but so what?

Comment: An array is probably the fastest way to do it. Maps are not for sorting, but for searching, to misuse them for sorting, if at all possible, will be slower.

Comment: What are you trying to do? How are you going to use the data?

Comment: Are you needing to sort on insertion, or just one after everything is inserted?

Comment: If you have a List already, I would sort the list with `Collections.sort()` any other approach has to sort the data AND build a new data structure which is likely to be slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you've told us, it's hard to say what'd be best.

If you're concerned with sorting performance alone, a HashTable or TreeMap (actually a red-black binary tree) have great sorting performance, but they're slower than some other data structures when adding (and in TreeMap's case, deleting) items.

You should probably provide more details regarding what you're doing with the data.

Comment: He is looking to sort the values not the keys